# android download file cannot parsing the package Parse error

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, parse-error, android-download-manager

What is my code problem:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {

        InputStream input = null;

        URLConnection conection = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bout = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        int downloaded = 0;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            conection = url.openConnection();
            //conection.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();


            conection = null;
            conection = url.openConnection();

            if(STATUS) {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myapp.apk");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    downloaded = (int) file.length();
                    conection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (file.length()) + "-");
                }
            }
            else {
                conection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-")
            }

            conection.setDoInput(true);
            conection.setDoOutput(true);



            input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            fos=(downloaded==0)? new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myapp.apk"): new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myapp.apk",true);
            bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);



            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;
            int count = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }

                bout.write(data, 0, count);
                downloaded += count;
                publishProgress((int)(downloaded * 100/ lenghtOfFile) );
                total += count;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
                if (fos != null)
                    fos.close();
                if (bout != null)
                    bout.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (conection != null)
                conection = null;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and I set this launcher to notification bar when clicked it:

```
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.down_icon)
            .setOngoing(true);



    resultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DownloadsActivity.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

when file downloaded completely and clicked notification bar I see this error:

```
There is a problem parsing the package
```

What is my code problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this your notification or is it provided by the system?

Comment: @hoomi It is by system, because I downloaded an apk file. I think issues is with my `doInBackground` method.

Comment: Do you get any sort of Exceptions or warning in the LogCat?

Comment: @hoomi No, file downloaded completely, but incorrect.

Comment: Is it possible that when you appended to the file they corrupted the file? as this line `fos=(downloaded==0)? new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myapp.apk"): new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myapp.apk",true);`

Comment: @hoomi I think too, what is your suggestion?

Comment: If your apk is not very big I suggest that you remove the previous one and create a new file

Comment: @hoomi I do it, and even replace with another apk or another url from different sites, but it is still incorrupted file.

Comment: Have you tried adding `bout.flush()` after your while loop? Maybe not all the bytes are written to your file

Comment: @hoomi OMG Damn Me. I was a terrible mistake. Thanks alot hoomi. You save my day. Please rewrite answer this for accepted answer. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem dude. I myself hate these types of errors ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding bout.flush() after your while loop? Maybe not all the bytes are written to your file